# NSMenuItem -setTarget: Does it retain the target?

Tags: cocoa, macos, retain, nsmenuitem

NSMenuItem -setTarget: Does it retain the target, or should one explicitly retain it?

I've seen conflicting docs on this. I know of retainArguments in NSInvocation, but I'm not sure this applies to NSMenuItem as it doesn't inherit from NSInvocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply look at the header:

```objc
@property (nullable, weak) id target;
```

or in Swift:

```swift
weak var target: AnyObject? { get set }
```

Here we see that `target` is `weak`, meaning that [it doesn't have control over the target's lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11013587/3939277). In technical terms, it neither increments nor decrements the reference count. Once your target is deallocated for any reason, `NSMenuItem` loses it too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it does. Usually target-action methods and delegate properties don't retain what they're set to, as they don't “own” their target.

Comment: It's a good idea to file an enhancement request by using the link at the bottom of the relevant page. A quick look at the -setTarget: API reference confirmed this is not stated either way, though it should be.