# Understanding weak vs. strong reference

Tags: objective-c, ios, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between strong and weak in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013587/differences-between-strong-and-weak-in-objective-c)

Let's say I have a tableview that displays a model object's data. If I declare in my UITableViewController...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *modelObject;
```

If I pass this array to another view controller property in a segue should it be declared `weak` in my destination view controller?

Comment: I've read the definitions multiple times, I just want to validate that I'm implementing correctly in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, either should work.

`strong` is a problem if the property can hold a `strong` circular reference back to the referencing object.  I suppose that's a possibility here but, assuming controllers aren't treated as data, not likely.  Since your initiating controller is going to stay around and hold a `strong` reference during the lifetime of your destination controller, then having a `weak` property in the destination should be OK too.

One reason that I might choose `strong` is as insurance against problems as the app evolves.  If there's any chance that the destination might someday receive its `modelObject` from some other source, are you going to remember that the provider must have a strong reference?