# pointer to non-const type Tile * with no explicit ownership

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to enable arc in my application but when xcode check my project then it is giving one error on given below line.

```
Tile ***grid;
```

**Error:** pointer to non-const type Tile * with no explicit ownership.

Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: add some context. that line by itself is fine EXCEPT IF Tile is an NSObject

Comment: try reading http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#conversion-of-pointers-to-ownership-qualified-types

Comment: Tile is a object that my using to cut images into tiles, and it is object pass by reference.

Comment: but a *** ? oh well, see my answer anyway

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ARC cannot infer what storage type it should use. So you have to tell it!

```
    Tile * __strong **grid; // Strong reference to grid

    Tile * __weak **grid; // Weak reference to grid
```

More about strong and weak references can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013715/1861458)