# Objective-C: Object not nil, but empty

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, null, is-empty

In my app, after some asynch operation I'm calling the selector pointing to the method in my `ViewController`.
Sometimes it happens, that this `ViewController` is already `deallocated` after that `asynch` operation.
My question is how can I check whether the `ViewController` is already deallocated?
I have access to it as an `Id` variable. Simple checking whether it's `nil` doesn't work.
This is the proper value of the `ViewController`:

[image]

but this one causes crash:

[image]
How can I check if it's empty or sth like that? I'm new to `ObjectiveC`, so it might look like a layman question, but please help. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is how can I check whether the ViewController is already deallocated?

The answer is that you can't (however, see below).  When the object is deallocated, all that happens is that it's storage goes back on the heap to be reused.  Nothing happens to the content of that memory.  So your id pointer can either be pointing at the original non deallocated object, the original object but deallocated, a new object that has reused the storage or just garbage.

The old way around this is for the view controller (the delegate) to own the object doing the delegating (whatever it is doing the asynchronous operation).  The view controller would then nil the delegate property (which would be an assign property) on the object doing the delegating when the view controller gets deallocated.

With ARC, it's the same arrangement except the delegate property on the object doing the delegating is a **weak** property which means that ARC will automatically nil it when the delegate gets deallocated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've got just one more question. What about deallocating the object doing the delegating? It was created in my ViewController. Than the ViewController called an async action and before the action completed it has set delegate to nil and deallocated it self. Where should I dealloc the delegating object, when it's async action is completed?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to investigate using weak properties - these are supposed to nil themselves out when the object being referenced gets deallocated. The answer to this question should be useful:

[Differences between strong and weak in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013587/differences-between-strong-and-weak-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [DELEGATE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) or completion block