# Passing data via prepareForSegue works on simulator but NOT on device

Tags: ios

I have the following code that passes a URL to the destination controller which loads a url

StoreURLViewController.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"continueToStore"])
    {
        StoreWebViewController *controller = (StoreWebViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        NSString *url = self.storeUrl.text;
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:url forKey:@"storeUrl"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        controller.storeUrl = [StoreUrlViewController checkAndPrependProtocolForApiUrl:url];
        NSLog(@"%@", controller.storeUrl);
    }
}
```

I have the following code that checks to see if it has a url and loads a web view

StoreWebViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.storeUrl);
    if (self.storeUrl != nil)
    {
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[StoreWebViewController checkAndPrependProtocolForUrl:self.storeUrl]]]];
        self.webView.delegate = self;
    }    
}
```

On the simulator the URL is a string and loads the web page, but on the device it is nil and doesn't load the page.

Device Output for input http://google.com

```
2014-02-25 14:05:48.883 PHP Point Of Sale[2784:60b] (null)
2014-02-25 14:05:48.970 PHP Point Of Sale[2784:60b] (null)
```

Simulator Output for http://google.com

```
2014-02-25 14:09:10.703 PHP Point Of Sale[31811:70b] http://google.com
2014-02-25 14:09:10.775 PHP Point Of Sale[31811:70b] http://google.com
```

Comment: Check the value in `viewWillAppear`.  Is it set then?

Comment: is your device running an older version of iOS than Simulator ?

Comment: Nothing in viewWillAppear

Comment: Double-check the segue identifier too.  The simulator tends to be a bit tolerant of changes in case, where the actual device is very strict.  Make sure it's specified in your storyboard as `continueToStore` and not something like `ContinueToStore`

Comment: I would also recommend using `NSLog` to dump out the segue identifier in an else statement if it doesn't match `continueToStore`.

Comment: The segue matches and is being run, but somehow the url isn't making it to the StoreWebViewController. I have posted updated code.

Comment: The problem as I had a weak reference for the store url variable, I changed it to strong and it worked. Where can I find more information on this?

Comment: This SO answer is pretty good.  [Differences between strong and weak in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013587/differences-between-strong-and-weak-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

I had a weak reference to storeUrl. I changed it to strong and now it works in the simulator and device.