# Prepare for segue NSString becomes NSObject?

Tags: ios

I'm using a prepare for segue to send a string through to the next controller. It is set as a string right up to being sent (according to NSLog), but as soon as I log it on the next controller it is an NSObject and not a string and therefore the value has become null.

Here is the first view controller the bodyText field is what I am trying to send across to the next view controller:

```
#import "GFAddPostTextViewController.h"
#import "GFSelectGroupViewController.h"

@interface GFAddPostTextViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *bodyTextField;
@end

@implementation GFAddPostTextViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"selectGroup"]) {

        GFSelectGroupViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        destViewController.bodyText = self.bodyTextField.text;

        NSLog(@"%@", destViewController.bodyText);

    }

}


@end
```

Here is the header file of the receiving View Controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GFSelectGroupViewController : UITableViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *bodyText;
@end
```

And finally the implementation file of the Receiving View Controller (The save method is where I call self.bodyText and where it is going wrong as it thinks bodytext is null):

```
#import "GFSelectGroupViewController.h"
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import "GFCredentialStore.h"
#import "GFGroupResponseSerializer.h"

#define kBaseURL "http://someserver.com/"
#define kGroupURL "groups.json"
#define kPostURL "posts.json"

@interface GFSelectGroupViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *groups;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
@end

@implementation GFSelectGroupViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GFCredentialStore *credentialStore = [[GFCredentialStore alloc] init];

    NSString *authToken = [credentialStore authToken];
    NSLog(@"%@", authToken);

    __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

    [self.saveButton setTarget:self];
    [self.saveButton setAction:@selector(save:)];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s", kBaseURL, kGroupURL];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [GFGroupResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"auth_token"];
    NSLog(@"%@", manager.requestSerializer.HTTPRequestHeaders);
    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        __strong typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.groups = (NSArray *)responseObject;
        [strongSelf.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

-(void)save:(id)sender {

    NSString * postURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s", kBaseURL, kPostURL];

    NSString *body = self.bodyText;
    NSLog(@"%@", body);

    NSDictionary *params = @{ @"post[body]" : body};


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:postURL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

New to iOS so any help highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Something seems a bit odd about you having a NSString as an IBOutlet, is that supposed to be a UILabel or something?

Comment: Remove `IBOutlet` from your string, make it `copy` (instead of `weak`) and give it a go...

Comment: You have a `weak` `NSString` property - which means that if you assign an object to that property, and there is no other `strong` reference pointing to it, it will be deallocated - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013587/differences-between-strong-and-weak-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the property declaration. You declared the string as `weak` (and `IBOutlet`, it shouldn't be that too).

Under [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) rules, this object will be removed from memory as soon as all strong pointers are not pointing to it anymore. Because you set it in the `prepareForSegue` method, it is nulled before you access it. So change your property declaration to:

```
@interface GFSelectGroupViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *bodyText;
@end
```

And in `prepareForSegue` method, set it like this:

```
...
GFSelectGroupViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

destViewController.bodyText = [self.bodyTextField.text copy];
...
```

Also help yourself with debugging, print out the variable in the `viewDidLoad` method of `GFSelectGroupViewController`, to see it is copied correctly.

Comment: Not only does this work perfectly, I understand why now. Thanks a lot I've accepted and upvoted.