# implemented delegate method but told it's not implemented

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to implement delegation. In the .h file of a custom class , I do this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Timer;

@protocol TimerDelegate

-(void)myClassDelegateMethod:(Timer *)timer;

@end

typedef void(^MyCustomBlock)(void);

@interface Timer : UILabel
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <TimerDelegate> delegate;
```

In the .m file I synthesize the delegate and also called the delegate method, checking to see first if the delegate implements the method

```
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)countdownTime:(NSTimer *)timer 
{
    NSLog(@"countdownTime called");
    ....
    [self.delegate myClassDelegateMethod:self];
    if (self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myClassDelegateMethod:)]) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(myClassDelegateMethod:)];
    } else {
    NSLog(@"Delegate doesn't implement myClassDelegateMethod");
    }
```

when I run my code, I'm told the delegate doesn't implement the method. Here's how I implement it
In the viewController, I declare that it conforms to the protocol

```
@interface scViewController : UIViewController  <TimerDelegate>
```

And then in the .m file of the viewController, I implement the delegate's method

```
- (void) myClassDelegateMethod:(Timer *) sender {
    NSLog(@"Delegates are great!");
}
```

Can you explain how I've failed to implement the delegate method properly?

Update, in the viewController, I have a method that creates timer instances

```
-(Timer *)timer
{
    _timer = [[Timer alloc] init];


    return _timer;
}
```

In viewDidLoad, I do this

```
 self.timer.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Do you ever do `timer.delegate = scViewController`? i.e. do you ever assign a delegate to a `Timer` instance?

Comment: @Rich thanks, yes, I do this in viewDidLoad of the vc  `self.timer.delegate = self;`

Comment: Also you declare `myClassDelegateMethod:` with an argument but `performSelector:` without one... Does the code crash, or does it log out "_Delegate doesn't implement myClassDelegateMethod_"?

Comment: @rich noted, however if you look at my code (updated), I also call it this way with an argument `[self.delegate myClassDelegateMethod:self];` and the log statement in the implementation in delegate never gets logged. There's no crash.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed your edit. Have you checked what `self.delegate` is? Is it `nil`?

Comment: @Rich, yes, I just logged ` NSLog(@"self delegate %@", self.delegate);` in the countdownTime method and it's (null)

Comment: Show the code were you create the `Timer` instance and set its `delegate` property.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil how is the `timer` property declared?

Comment: seems you're doing `self.timer.delegate = self;` too soon. i.e. before `_timer = [[Timer alloc] init];`

Comment: @staticVoidMan `self.timer` would call the `timer` getter and create a new instance...

Comment: @Rich : huh... so you're saying that if i `@property` and `@synthesize` `ABC *abc;` and simply do `self.abc;` that will be equivalent to `abc = [[ABC alloc] init];`? nah... i am sure the delegate was being set prematurely

Comment: @staticVoidMan as he's written the above question, yes it would create a new instance each time.

Comment: @Rich : oh ok, right... _didn't think much about `-(Timer *)timer`_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `timer` method is a problem. It should be:

```
-(Timer *)timer
{
    if (!_timer) {
        _timer = [[Timer alloc] init];
    }

    return _timer;
}
```

As you have it, every time you do `self.timer` you were creating a new timer so the delegate was only applied to one of the many instances.

Comment: You'd have to make sure that `timer` property is declared as `strong` too?

Comment: ok, thanks, actually there was a reason why that I'm creating a new timer every instance (i.e. I'm creating multiple timers), so I instead set the delegate in this factory method `_timer.delegate = self;` works fine now.

Comment: That moment when you're typing an answer only to see @rmaddy's pop up for the win.

Comment: @Rich - Yes, it needs to be strong.

Comment: @Rich I did, but don't know why that's important (if you can explain)

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil If you are creating multiple timers, then how do you expect a single instance variable to work?

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil to save me typing see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11013715/849645)!

Comment: @rmaddy a single instance variable to work for what? I don't get what you mean?

Comment: @rmaddy I create multiple instances of the timer in viewDidLoad in the vc but it was my mistake to set delegate for only one of the instances