# cyclic references for protocol variables

Tags: swift

Cyclic references getting formed in this example, however I can't apply unowned or weak to protocol variables, what's the workaround in this situation.

```
protocol Report {
    func done()
}

class Employee {
    unowned var report: Report? //error here with using unowned or weak

    func whenIAmDone() {
        report.done()
    }
}

class Supervisor: Report {
    var employees: [Employee]?

    init() {
        for i in 1...5 {
            var employee = Employee()
            employee.report = self
            employees?.append(employee)
        }
    }

    func done() {
        println("work done by...")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `Report` protocol as *class-only* by adding `class` to its declaration:

```
protocol Report: class {
    func done()
}
```

You have a separate issue there, with disagreement between your choice of "weak" keywords and the `report` property being optional. Here's the rule: `weak` instances are always optional, `unowned` instances are never optional. `Employee` should look like this:

```
class Employee {
    weak var report: Report? //error here with using unowned or weak

    func whenIAmDone() {
        report?.done()
    }
}
```

or if you want `report` to be unowned, it would need to be a non-Optional, but then you need an initializer that can give it a value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your protocol as class-only like below.

```
protocol Report : class {
    func done()
}


class Employee {
    weak var report: Report? 

    func whenIAmDone() {
        report?.done()
    }
}
```

Read this to learn the difference between weak and unowned. [What is the difference between a weak reference and an unowned reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011575/what-is-the-difference-between-a-weak-reference-and-an-unowned-reference)