# If "self" is the ViewController, should you almost always use [weak self]?

Tags: ios, swift, oop, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've always been using [weak self] in every callback in the event that the controller unwinds and "self" can become nil.

Is this the right approach?

What are some examples when I should use [unowned self] or neither...assuming "self" is a ViewController that will frequently get unwinded?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011575/what-is-the-difference-between-a-weak-reference-and-an-unowned-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is possible that the callback will still be called when the `self` has been deinitialized, using `[weak self]` is correct. The reason to use `[unowned self]` would be cases where you know the callback will never be called after `self` is gone, but strongly capturing `self` would lead to a retain cycle.

An example of `[unowned self]` would be a case where the closure's existence depends on the existence of `self`, then it is clear that if `self` is gone the closure will be gone as well and won't be called.

Comment: To be safe, should I just use [weak self] all the time? Assuming self is a view controller.  What would be the effects if I used weak self everywhere? Would memory get released "slower" or something?

Comment: @TIMEX Well, if you are not sure that `unowned self` is safe in a particular case, use `weak self`. The closure will then be a bit more complex to make (since `weak` makes `self` an optional) and might have a theoretical impact on performance, but given that using a `__weak` reference has been common practice in Objective-C, it's not going to be catastrophic (also, premature optimization =).