# Swift using function parameter inside closure

Tags: swift, memory, closures

I just want to use function parameter inside swift closure without memory leak, so I just want to confirm if I do in following way will there be any memory related issues? Kindly let me know

```
func someMethod(someValue: String) {
    weak var weakSelf = self
    var copyOfSomeValue: String? = someValue.copy() as? String
    self.someOtherMethodWithCompletion(completionHandler: { () -> Void in
        if let strongSelf = weakSelf, let originalValue = copyOfSomeValue {
            strongSelf.updateMyViewWithText(originalValue)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` is a [value type](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10). Even though closures [capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID103) them by reference, there is no need to make a copy unless you are going to change `someValue` after the capture. Even then you're better off using capture lists `[someValue]`, which are also used when you need to declare `[weak self]`.

Using `weak` or `unowned` is situational, read about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011575/what-is-the-difference-between-a-weak-reference-and-an-unowned-reference).

```
func someMethod(someValue: String) {
    someOtherMethodWithCompletion { [weak self] in
        self?.updateMyViewWithText(someValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With swift you should use `[unowned self]` and just use swift as normal, for example:

```
func someMethod(someValue: String) {
    var copyOfSomeValue: String? = someValue.copy() as? String
    self.someOtherMethodWithCompletion(completionHandler: { () ->
        [unowned self]
         in
        if let originalValue = copyOfSomeValue {
            self.updateMyViewWithText(originalValue)
        }
    })
}
```

You should use weak or unowned just to variables which can cause reference cycle. The difference between those is:

> Use a weak reference whenever it is valid for that reference to become
>   nil at some point during its lifetime. Conversely, use an unowned
>   reference when you know that the reference will never be nil once it
>   has been set during initialization

Comment: So can I use unowned for any of my instance variables inside a closure?