# Unowned Reference causes leak , weak doesn't

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I'm experiencing some kind of memory management issue. I have a subclass of `UIViewController` and I set its view manually in order to have a reference back to the `viewController` and to avoid reference cycle I use `weak/unowned`.
Now the problem is , if I use `unowned` I have a memory leak but if I use `weak` I don't have one. I can't figure out why this happens?

update:
It seems like it's a bug.

console output:

```
removing vc
view Controller deinitialized
custom view deinitialized
```

I'm using xcode 8.3.1

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { 
        print("removing vc")
        self.window?.rootViewController = nil
    }

    return true
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = CustomView(frame: .zero, vc: self)
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    deinit {
        print("view Controller deinitialized")
    }
}

class CustomView:UIView{

    init(frame: CGRect , vc:ViewController) {
        self.vc = vc
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //    weak var vc : ViewController!   // no leak
    unowned var vc : ViewController   // leak

    deinit {
        print("custom view deinitialized")
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you determining that you have a leak? Maybe your method is wrong or this is (less likely) a compiler bug

Comment: both instruments and memory graph show that, this is a leak.

Comment: Neither weak nor unowned hold a strong reference. So it can't be the reason for a leak. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26025176/6595536

Comment: I know that. But this is the whole code, nothing else can cause the problem and also with weak there is no leak. Maybe it's a bug!

Comment: Please @Alan try to override `deinit` and print some info there and check this way, as the instruments tool for swift may not work properly yet. I personally encountered false positives there. Maybe your leak is not even a leak.

Comment: Do you use Xcode 8.1.3? There was an official problem with the leak tool. Try check again with Xcode 8.2!

Comment: Might not help you at all, but as a rule of thumb, if you follow MVC pattern, your view shouldn't really be linking back to your view controller like this. For instance, create a delegate protocol to support such communication.

Comment: thanks @Alistra . you're right.it's not a leak.

Comment: @PauloMattos . thanks for the hint , but this is part of a bigger problem that mvc can't solve.

Comment: as @Alistra said, there is no leak. I have tested it using Instruments Tool. 
Clearly from apple doc [link] https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html. Check for Unowned References section.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 8.2 Release notes:

> The Memory Debugger for macOS and the iOS Simulator fixes reporting of
>   false memory leaks for Swift classes containing either fields of type
>   enum, or classes that inherit from certain Objective-C framework
>   classes. (27932061)