# What does [unowned self] mean and what are the benefits?

Tags: swift, biometrics, touch-id, face-id, lacontext

I´m trying to integrate Face/Touch ID Login and I saw `[unowned self]` in Apple's documentation, inside a closure. What is that and what are the benefits?

Example code:

```
let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Identify yourself!"
        
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {
            [unowned self] (success, authenticationError) in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    print("Authenticated!")
                } else {
                    // error
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // no biometry
    }
```

Comment: [Might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift); ["WEAK, STRONG, UNOWNED, OH MY!"](https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift); [Swift Retention Cycle in Closures and Delegate](https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/swift-retention-cycle-in-closures-and-delegate-836c469ef128); [Automatic Reference Counting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html); [How To Prevent Memory Leaks In Swift Closures](https://stablekernel.com/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-swift-closures/)

Comment: [Unowned vs Weak](https://medium.com/@fahad_29644/unowned-vs-weak-614ac71ac516); [Functional programming: Closure reference cycle and fix](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/functional-programming-closure-reference-cycle-and-fix-f42cc53c6213)

Comment: will look into it later. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shall we always use \[unowned self\] inside closure in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

The `unowned` qualifier, like `weak`, prevents the closure from establishing a strong reference to to `self` which can be helpful in preventing strong reference cycles. The benefit of `unowned` over `weak` is that it’s a tad more efficient in optimized builds, not requiring it to keep track of this reference and go back and set it to `nil` when the object to which it references is deallocated. The `unowned` reference also is not an optional, meaning that you don’t have to unwrap it, eliminating syntactic noise and simplifying one’s code.

But you obviously can’t use `unowned` in any situation where the object might be deallocated, because it obviously can no longer keep a reference to the memory for a deallocated object.

Interestingly, the `evaluatePolicy(_:localizedReason:reply:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514176-evaluatepolicy) says, “This method asynchronously evaluates an authentication policy.” Any time you’re dealing with an asynchronous method, it is not advisable to use `unowned`, because you cannot be assured that the object in question hasn’t been deallocated in the intervening time. Only use `unowned` in those specific situations where you know, for a fact, that the closure cannot be called if the object has been deallocated. That would not appear to be the case here.

Bottom line, use `unowned` to avoid strong reference cycles and where you want cleaner, slightly more efficient code. But *only* do so when you know that it is impossible for the object to be deallocated before closure is called.

Comment: what do you mean with deallocated?

Comment: When the last strong reference is removed, the object will be deallocated and the memory it used to occupy will be made available for other purposes. In the case of a view controller, it generally is deallocated once it’s dismissed. So if you have a view controller that is dismissed before the asynchronous closure is called, the `unowned` reference will be a dangling pointer, still point to the memory it used to occupy, whereas a `weak` reference will be set to `nil` as soon as the view controller is deallocated, avoiding any unsafe references to the old memory address.

Comment: so with unowned i have always access to self even if the viewcontroller is deallocated right?

Comment: That depends upon what you mean by “access to”. If the view controller has been deallocated, you obviously don’t have “access to” it, because it’s gone. What you’ve got is a reference to that location of memory that assumes the view controller is still there, even though it’s not. In short, if it’s at all possible for `self` to be deallocated before the closure runs, you simply shouldn’t use `unowned`. But if you’ve got a different scenario where it’s technically impossible for it to be deallocated before the closure runs, then use `unowned` and enjoy the modest benefits.

Comment: "but only when you know that it is impossible for the object to be deallocated before closure is called." like when? Do you have an answer that actually requires `unowned` to be used? I can't find one that's simple to understand :/

Comment: See [The Swift Programming Language: ARC: Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID57) for examples. Common scenario is (a) the closure is called synchronously; and (b) the closure is called by something further down the object ownership graph. A practical example: a `UIButton` subclass has closure property that is called when the button is tapped. View controller can safely use `[unowned self]` in capture list because if the view controller is dismissed, the button is gone, too.

Comment: Here is a contemporary link re breaking strong reference cycles: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/automaticreferencecounting/#Resolving-Strong-Reference-Cycles-for-Closures

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it's the same as `weak!`, since unowned references are just weak references that are guaranteed to have a value.

`unowned` is used when you're sure that the reference will **NEVER** be nil, and therefore, it can only be evaluated with non nil values.

> Like weak references, an unowned reference does not keep a strong hold on the instance it refers to. Unlike a weak reference, however, an unowned reference is assumed to always have a value. Because of this, an unowned reference is always defined as a non-optional type. **(Apple Docs)**

Check this other answer: 
[What is the difference between a weak reference and an unowned reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26493007/8869493)

**Docs:** [ARC Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)