# weak vs unowned inside Swift Combine closure

Tags: swift, combine

I don't understand the correct way of using `self` inside Combine closure

```
class ViewModel {
    var requestPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var nextPageAvailabe = true
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        setupSubscriptions()
    }

    setupSubscriptions() {
        requestPublisher
        .filter { _ in self.nextPageAvailabe }
        .sink(receiveValue: {
            print("Received request")  
        }).store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

`requestPublisher.send()` executed from parent class.
Using `.filter { _ in self.nextPageAvailabe }` will lead to memory leak. So I need to use `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` inside `filter {}`. And both solve the memory leak issue, but I don't understand the correct way. I have read several articles but couldn't find the answer. So what is the correct way of using `self` inside Combine closure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a weak reference and an unowned reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011575/what-is-the-difference-between-a-weak-reference-and-an-unowned-reference)

Comment: @Andrew no, your link describe weak vs unowned inside plane swift not Combine.

Comment: A closure is a closure it doesn’t matter whether it is used in combine or not.

Comment: I have read this article several times, but still don't understand what to use in this case...

Comment: It's to do with the life time of the object that is being captured by the closure. If you can guarantee that it will never be released before the closure is executed then you can use `unowned` if you don't know if it will be released or if you are unsure then use `weak`.

Comment: In sort [weak self] alway works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This capture list creates an unowned reference to self in the closure or completion block. In this case, if the view controller is deallocated before the closure or completion block is executed, it will cause a runtime crash. Therefore, it’s essential to use unowned references only when it is entirely sure that they will not become nil during block execution. Such a “safe” case would be when we store AnyCancellable in the same class where closure was defined.

It seems, that in this case we can use `unowned` without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

`weak` is definitely the way to go : you will just have an optional `self`. When a `weak` variable is released, it just becomes nil.

`unowned` should be avoided as much as possible, as it is not runtime-safe : it is like `weak`, but the result is not optional. So if you try to use an unowned variable after it has been released, the app will simply crash.

```swift
    setupSubscriptions() {
        requestPublisher
        .filter { [weak self] _ in self?.nextPageAvailabe ?? false }
// I have put `?? false` because I suppose that if self is nil, then page is not available...
        .sink(receiveValue: {
            print("Received request")  
        }).store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
```

Comment: https://www.kodeco.com/books/combine-asynchronous-programming-with-swift - in the same case use unowned

Comment: `unowned` *might* be OK in this case because when the object is destroyed its subscription is also destroyed which should prevent any of the closures in the observer chain from being called.  Where you would get into trouble is if you shared the subscription with someone else. Even though it might work, using `weak` is the safer alternative, requires less critical thinking, doesn't introduce too much overhead, and so its generally a better habit to use `weak` instead of `unowned`.