# Should I use weak self when I getting new Notification in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui

I am posing a notification and also i am getting the notification and the app works, my app would be working with or without `weak self` so I am little confused about using or not using it, maybe some one could help me and show me if i need `weak self` and why I need it or why i do not need it here.

This code is for macOS Storyboard Cocoa project.

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

var appName: String = "My App Name"

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: myNotificationName, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] newNotification in
            
            if let unwrappedNewNotification = newNotification.object as? String {
                self?.titleUpdater(value: unwrappedNewNotification)
            }
        }
        
        let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        self.view = controller.view
        self.view.window?.title = appName
    }
    
    private func titleUpdater(value: String) {
        appName = value
        self.view.window?.title = value
    }
    
}





struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change", action: {
                postMyNotification(value: appName + " updated!")
            })
        }
        .frame(width: 400.0, height: 300.0)
    }
}




let myNotificationName: Notification.Name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "myNotificationName")

func postMyNotification(value: String) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: myNotificationName, object: value))
}
```

---

Update:

```
deinit {
    if let unwrappedObserver: NSObjectProtocol = observer {
        print("worked for deinit!")
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(unwrappedObserver)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/weak-self/

Comment: Lots of good insights here: [What is the difference between a weak reference and an unowned reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011575/what-is-the-difference-between-a-weak-reference-and-an-unowned-reference)

Comment: @jnpdx: I read that article could not help myself, it defines imaginary examples and issues which we never going have those issue in real project. I do not recommend it to others.

Comment: Strongly disagree -- programming issues almost _always_ are defined in abstract ways. I highly recommend that article, but I understand it may not be useful for everyone.

Comment: @jnpdx: I think it was difficult for me to understand or find a use case from examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use `weak self` in this case, because `NotificationCenter` has to hold on to the closure strongly. If you don't use `weak self`, your `ViewController` can never be destroyed.

But you should also ensure that your observer is destroyed when the `ViewController` is destroyed. The `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)` method returns an object which you should save in an instance property and pass to `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver` in `deinit`.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private var observer: NSObjectProtocol? = nil

    deinit {
        if let observer {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: myNotificationName, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] newNotification in
            
            if let unwrappedNewNotification = newNotification.object as? String {
                self?.titleUpdater(value: unwrappedNewNotification)
            }
        }

        let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        self.view = controller.view
        self.view.window?.title = appName
    }

    private func titleUpdater(value: String) {
        appName = value
        self.view.window?.title = value
    }
}
```

But I would recommend using a different API so you don't have to write a `deinit` at all. Use Combine instead, like this:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: myNotificationName)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in
                if let self, let newTitle = $0.object as? String {
                    self.titleUpdater(value: newTitle)
                }
            }
            .store(in: &tickets)

        let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        self.view = controller.view
        self.view.window?.title = appName
    }

    private func titleUpdater(value: String) {
        appName = value
        self.view.window?.title = value
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to write a `deinit`. When the `ViewController` is destroyed, it automatically destroys its instance properties, including the `tickets` array and its contents. When the ticket (`AnyCancellable`) returned by `sink` is destroyed, it cancels the subscription.

You might even be able to eliminate the use of `self` entirely. You didn't show the declaration of `appName`. If it's global, you can subscribe like this instead:

```
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: myNotificationName)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [view] in
                if let newTitle = $0.object as? String {
                    appName = newTitle
                    view.window?.title = newTitle
                }
            }
            .store(in: &tickets)
```

Now the closure captures `view` directly instead of capturing `self`, so there's no possibility of a retain cycle.

Comment: I just start informing myself about `weak self` or `unowned self` or strong, what I found was that I do not need a strong self there because title has some old value there and my app would not crash if new title does not updated, also I do not think `unowned self` needed here because there is possibility that I never tap on button to update and it can be nil, so just `weak self` left to chose, is that true what I found?

Comment: Also you said: "ensure that your observer is destroyed" if I want keep using my code in question and not using your answer could you add that part of code at your answer please as a reference for learning and correcting my codes?

Comment: I added code to show how to destroy the observer in `deinit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I just like that you look my updated code for my question from your answer if it is also correct?, and I tried to trigger the `deinit` but I was unable to get that print! If I am unable to see that print so that method is not going called! I know that it is a must and needed method but what is the point if it does not triggered?  at least I could not make it to get triggered! can you show me a way to see that `deinit` is going triggered?