# What is the difference between a var and a weak var in Swift

Tags: swift, memory-management, weak-references

What is the difference between a `var` and a `weak var` in Swift?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has to do with how [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) manages memory of your objects.

Using `var` defines a *strong* reference to the object, while using `weak var` defines a *weak* reference to the object.

Objects are kept in memory for as long as there remains one or more strong references to that object.  Using a weak reference allows you to hold a reference to an object without increasing what is known as its "retain count".

If nothing else holds a reference to your `weak var`, the object will be deallocated, and your `weak var` will decay to `nil`.<sup>1</sup>  This won't happen when you just use `var`, as this defines a strong reference to the object, which should prevent it from deallocating.

This is identical to how "strong" vs "weak" works in Objective-C, and I recommend you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013715/2792531), as it applies exactly to Swift.

<sup>1</sup>*As a Swift specific note, this is the reason why anything declared as a `weak var` must be an optional type.*