# Strong and Weak Confusion in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am little confused about using `Strong` or `Weak` in my particular case.

I have one class `ParentClass` which has `3 object` `ContainerClass1`, `ContainerClass2` and `ContainerClass3`.

Each `ContainerClass` has its own strong properties with Mutable objects like `NSMutableArray`

Now in my case, I have to show only one `ContainerClass` at a time, so if `ContainerClass1` is shown then `ContainerClass2` and `ContainerClass3` is not required.

So I thought when I show `ContainerClass1`, will set `ContainerClass2` and `ContainerClass3` objects to `nil`. Here I am confused whether just setting the other `ContainerClass`(not shown) to `nil` will `release` its memory? because they have strong properties to other objects.

Or should I need to set all other `ContainerClass's` strong properties to `nil` first and then set `ContainerClass` to `nil`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all you should always set weak for IBOutlets. And yes when you set ContainerClass2 to nil its all IBOutlets become nil, because its parent is nil.

Comment: Agree Yogesh for IBOutlets :)

Comment: http://www.rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I edited my question now it's not all about IBOutlets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@zoeb, may this link will help you to keep away from basic memory problems.

[how-to-overcome-memory-problems-in-iphone-applications-with-automatic-reference-counting](https://jptext.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/how-to-overcome-memory-problems-in-iphone-applications-with-arcautomatic-reference-counting/)

**Edited:**

As we know that Apple introduced ARC in IOS 5.0, ARC is compiler level feature that simplifies process of lifetime of objective-c objects. Before ARC introduced, We managed memory manually means “Manual Reference Counting(MRC)” . With MRC, Developer need to remember when to release or retain object. Means that Developer need to manage life cycle of objective-c objects.

According to Developer perspective, We are mostly interested to adding new features in our application rather then focusing on memory issues. But the things is sure that memory management perform crucial role in application success. To Provide help to Developer, Apple was figure out the way of automatically manage memory.

ARC is smartly manage memory but this is not 100 percent. We need to focus on some points while development to remove our application from lack of memory problem. Here i will try to provide solution of manage memory in ARC base application. that is not 100 percent as well. but its will try to help compiler to estimate life cycle of objective object.

Here are the some steps that you need to implement in your every controllers.

**Step 1.** Declare weak property to every UI Controls that used in application.

Example : 
`@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton* btnPost;`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* tblMessages;
```

etc.

**Step 2.** As per our developer most confusing question is that whether compiler allow to declare “dealloc” method in ARC base application. the answer is yes but don’t allowed to declare “[super dealloc]” inside it. so override “dealloc” method in every controllers.

```
-(void)dealloc{

}
```

**Step 3.** Remove heavy loaded object from superview in “dealloc” method rather then setting just “nil” reference like MKMapview, ScrollView etc.

```
-(void)dealloc{
dictAddress = nil;
arrayList = nil;
[map removeFromSuperview];
[scrollView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Step 4.** Avoid dead lock mechanism. (Example : Class A and Class B is there. Class B is declared Delegate with property type “Strong”. so that Class A and Class B dependent on each other on one is going to release. so in that case “dealloc” method is not called of either classes. so that class keep in memory. to removed such cases we need to keep “Assign” reference to Delegate object.) this is just for example. We need to consider other things as well like “Keep weak reference for block so it will release objects once its execution completed”.

these are the basic steps that avoiding memory problems. Still if you face memory problems then you need to take help of Analyzer to find leak and memory usage.

Below link will help you to analyze memory.

[Mamory analyzer](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks)

Comment: Ohh I thought dealloc will not call automatically in ARC

Comment: `dealloc` is also called in ARC. so set `nil` reference to strong variable.

Comment: @None - ARC **automatically** handles strong (and weak) references, that is the point. There is **no** need to use `dealloc` to set strong variables to `nil`. So step 3 is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion between strong and weak will be clear with the below link.

[Differences between strong and weak in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013587/differences-between-strong-and-weak-in-objective-c)