# In Objective C, When is weak object released under ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Since the reference count becoming 0 will cause the object being released.
I am curious when is a weak object released since the count is always 0, when I declare a weak one, do I need to worry about it will be released half way?

For example

```
NSObject ClassA

@property (weak) NSString stringA;


- init() {
    ...
    stringA = @"this is a weak string";
    ...
}

- doSomething() {
    // When I call this function later, 
    // is there any chance at this point stringA has been released?
    NSLog(stringA);
}
```

Comment: Presumably something else still has a strong reference, no?

Comment: For example, I have a class, there is a member: `@property (weak) NSObject object;` when does it be released?

Comment: How are you assigning to that? Where is the object coming from? If there is no strong reference to it anywhere, I would be worried...

Comment: Please refer this link:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html

Comment: what if I just assign it by `object.object = anObject;`

Comment: I added an example in question.

Comment: Strings are a bad example. They are "special". But yes, if you assign to your weak property in one method, and no one else has another reference to it, then it can have been released before `doSomething`. That's the point of weak references, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only declare a weak property **if it was connected via an `IBOutlet` or a as a `delegate`/`datasource`** (references another `UIViewController`).

If you make a weak property, it will be released immediately after instantiating it. However, a `weak` property connected via an `IBOutlet` will not release because the view holds strongly to the property.

Same with properties of type VCs, such as `delegate`s, they are `weak` properties because you assign your class to the property. The VC is obviously held strongly so the delegate should refrain from holding strongly to the VC to prevent retain cycles (where `a` holds strongly to `b` and `b` holds strongly to `a`).

**So to answer your question**, a `weak` property will be released immediately if nothing holds strongly to it, and the above is scenarios where you will use a `weak` property.

Comment: If you connect a view with `IBOutlet` and declare it as `weak` it will be released after the view is no longer used. If you have a window and you change its contents to show another view the old one will be released.

Comment: @Arc676 but that's intended behaviour. Unless you're strongly holding on to the instance of the view controller that uses the view and are presenting it repeatedly, chances are you're probably initialising a new instance every time.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are a bad example. There are certain objects that get never released. Constant strings, [NSNull null], @YES and @NO, small NSNumber values in 32 bit and many NSNumber values in 64 bit, empty arrays, and so on. Since they are not released, a weak variable will never be nil.

Many objects are autoreleased. If nothing else references them but their autorelease pool, they go away when the pool goes away.

But if you create an object with alloc/init and store it in a weak variable, the compiler knows that alloc/init had a reference count of 1, that reference count is removed, and poof! it goes. If you store the reference into a local variable first which is strong by default, it goes away when the code leaves the scope of the local variable. If you store into a weak variable first and then from the weak variable immediately into a strong one, it is too late, it's gone.