# iOS Viewcontroller with reference to table view IBOutlet - Weak or Strong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

As I read in another question, a rule of thumb was:

When a parent has a reference to a child object, you should use a strong reference. When a child has a reference to its parent object, you should use a weak reference or a  unsafe_unretained one (if the former is not available). A typical scenario is when you deal with delegates. For example, a UITableViewDelegate doesn't retain a controller class that contains a table view.

Well, in this case I have a view controller with a table view IBOutlet. This table view also uses the view controller as a delegate and data source. By the rule above, the view controller acts as the parent and so I should have a strong reference to the table view - the table view should have a weak reference to the view controller.

I'm not sure how to define that latter weak reference - I'm setting

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

How am I supposed to make myself weak? Or is this not the right way to do it?

Comment: Just drag the outlet from your TableView in storyboard to your .h file. Xcode will take care of making it a weak IBOutlet

Answer (score 2):

You can just drag the outlet from your `UITableView` to your `.h` file. Xcode will create appropriate property for you. You can choose weak/strong type from there as well while naming the Outlet.

If you would however like to create it manually, you can add this line to your `.h` file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
```

But do keep in mind that even after adding this line to your `.h.` file, you will still have to connect it to your `UITableView`.

Also don't forget to make your ViewController conform to `UITableViewDelegate` like below:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

In your title however, you seem to be confused about the difference between Weak and Strong properties. [Ole Begemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116862/ole-begemann) has answered about the difference splendidly on [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013587/differences-between-strong-and-weak-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote is fine. You don't have to make yourself weak. The delegate and datasource properties are declare as weak in the UITableView [definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/delegate).

Answer (score 0):

**delegate** and **datasource** are already weak as per UITableView.h.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id <UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id <UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
```

If any instance is set as delegate and datasource won't get retained by tableview instance

And when you make a IBOutlet make it like this. Choose weak if its strong by default its weak as shown in image

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
```

[image]

As the view is already retained by the view it's added (i.e self.view)

Answer (score 0):

It is just like a view in UIKit Control to display data in list form. It is not a child controller. All UIKit items are referenced as weak.